# Connecting to oracle-tns from mulestudio

Tags: oracle, mule-studio, tns

I want to connect to oracle database with connection type "TNS" from Anypointstudio.
But I am not sure what is the Database URL that can be used for this purpose.
Below are the details

Database version: sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78

Username: muleuser  ,
Password: muleuser  ,
HOST:XX  ,
PORT: 1521  ,
SERVICE_NAME = XX
Connection Type: TNS

Please provide me the equivalent jdbc url and jdbc driver name which can be used to connect to db from Anypointstudio: Version: 5.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.
The problem was I was using older version of the jar
Now I use latest 0jdbc.14 and I am able to connect.

Thanks everyone for the quick response and help.
Keep it up

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQLDeveloper installed, I'm going to assume you have the thin client installed at least and that you can connect within SQLDeveloper.

The JDBC URL syntax is:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@HOSTNAME:1251:SID
```

"SID" can be either the database SID or the Service Name as specified in the listener.ora file

Comment: I tried the above url but still not able to connect . I am getting the error "TNS:listener does not currently know of the SID given in connector descriptor". I am able to connect from sql developer but not from mulestudio

Comment: In SQL/Developer can you please post your connection string in the database connection setup.

Comment: In SQL developer I donot pass any url.  I give the following details in ndividual field "ConnectionName", "UserName","password", "Connection_Type: TNS", "Network Alias"

Comment: Can you please guide how to configure in anypoint studio when you have a tns connection